# a problem with Lifting the exponent method

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $e(n)$ denote the exponent of the highest power of $2$, which divides $a_n=\frac {(3+2\sqrt {b+1})^n-(3-2\sqrt {b+1})^n}{ \sqrt {b+1} },$ with $b$ an odd integer. $n_n$ becomes from the recurence relation $a_{n+2}=6a_{n+1}+(4b-5) a_n$ with $a_0=0, a_1=4.$ I tried to use the (lifting the exponent) lemma to calculate $e(n)$, since:

(Lifting the exponent): Let $e(n)$ denote the highest power of a prime $p$ that divides $n$.

That is, $e(n)=k$ such that $p^k \mid n$ and $p^{k+1} \nmid n$ . We have the following relation: $$\large e(x^n-y^n) = e(x-y)+e(n)$$ for any odd prime $p.$ What can I do?